# What's the area enclosed by this two functions.

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

What is the area enclosed by these two functions:

$$y^2=x ~~\text{and}~~ y=x-1.$$

Please help me to find this.

Answer (score 1):

If you rotate the axes you get the equations $x=y^2$ and $x=y+1$. The area is enclosed by the parabola and a linear line. These functions intersect at $y_0$ and $y_1$ (let $y_0\leq y_1$) then then you get that the area is $$\int_{y_0}^{y_1}y+1dy-\int_{y_{0}}^{y_1}y^2dy$$ Try to make sense of this and try again.

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

Eliminate $x$ to find the [ordinate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinate) of intersection of the two curves, let the values of $y$ be $y_1,y_2$

The area will be $$\left|\int_{y_1}^{y_2}x\ dy\right|=\left|\int_{y_1}^{y_2}y^2\ dy\right|$$